# WriteFile, ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c++, file-io, wifi

I'm trying to my wifi connection to send data to a reciver for experimentations. I managed to connect the card to the reciver using the windows API Native for wifi.

I store the GUID of my card in pIfInfo pointer (PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO) and extract it to create the handle (WifiAcess) that should allow me to write on the connection.

Then if i run this I get the error ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER on the WriteFile function with and without the (void*) casting before envois.

Well, My problem is that, I don't know which parameter is invalid

```
DWORD bytesSend;
char *buffer ;
unsigned int nbChar ;
```

data to send

```
int headerData[4] = {85,0,11,0};
int ServosData[6] = {100,100,0,100,0,0};

 BYTE * envois = new BYTE[11];

 envois[0] = headerData[0] ;
 envois[1] = headerData[1] ;
 envois[2] = headerData[2] ;
 envois[3] = headerData[3] ;
 envois[4] = ServosData[0] ;
 envois[5] = ServosData[1] ;
 envois[6] = ServosData[2] ;
 envois[7] = ServosData[3] ;
 envois[8] = ServosData[4] ;
 envois[9] = ServosData[5] ;
```

check summ

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i<10;i++)
 {
     envois[10] = envois[10] + envois[i] ;
 }
 envois[10] = envois[10]%256 ;
 nbChar = 11 ;

 HANDLE WifiAcess = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
 LPCSTR AcessGUID ;
 char GuidString2Char[46] ;
 char DefChar = ' ';
 bool sendtOk = false ;
```

here we get the GUID of our Wlan card from the wifi connection

```
    sprintf(GuidString2Char, "\\\\.\\{%08lX-%04hX-%04hX-%02hhX%02hhX-%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX}",
                        pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid.Data1,
                        pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid.Data2,
                        pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid.Data3,
                        pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid.Data4[0],
                        pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid.Data4[1],
                        pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid.Data4[2],
                        pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid.Data4[3],
                        pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid.Data4[4],
                        pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid.Data4[5],
                        pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid.Data4[6],
                        pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid.Data4[7]);
```

Put the translated GUID in a LPCSTR

```
    AcessGUID = GuidString2Char ;
```

then create the Handle

```
    WifiAcess = CreateFile(
                                AcessGUID ,  
                                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                FILE_SHARE_READ ,
                                NULL,
                                OPEN_EXISTING,
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                                (HANDLE)INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE); // NULL
```

Check for errors

```
        if(WifiAcess == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            dwResult = GetLastError();
            switch(dwResult)
            {
                case ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND  :
                        wprintf(L"\t\t\CreateFile ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND\n");
                    break ;
                default :
                        wprintf(L"\t\t\CreateFile default\n");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {  wprintf(L"\t\t\CreateFile Success\n"); }
```

Try to write the buffer on the WifiAcess Handle

```
        sendtOk = WriteFile(WifiAcess, envois, nbChar, &bytesSend, NULL) ; 
        if(!sendtOk)
        {
            wprintf(L"\n\t\t\tEcheque de l envois : %d bytes envoyes\n\n", bytesSend);
            dwResult = GetLastError();
            switch(dwResult)
            {
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
                case ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER  :
                        wprintf(L"\t\t\WriteFile ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER\n");
                    break ;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
                case S_FALSE  :
                        wprintf(L"\t\t\WriteFile S_FALSE\n");
                    break ;
                case E_UNEXPECTED  :
                        wprintf(L"\t\t\WriteFile E_UNEXPECTED\n");
                    break ;
                default :
                        wprintf(L"\t\t\WriteFile default with dword : 0x%x \n", dwResult);
                    break;
            }

        }else
        {
            wprintf(L"Data Sendt\n\n");
        }
```

Comment: Just a guess: Many device drivers do not permit FILE_SHARE_READ

Comment: The Handle created is Valid...But 
To Check I Changed this parameter to NULL, it gives the same error.

Maybe there is some thing similar to serial com with "GetCommState" that is needed to set a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i'found what was wrong, the analogy with serial com cannot be used, instead i used the winsock class :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545(v=vs.85).aspx

=====================================================================================================
initialisation :

`WSADATA wsaData;`

```
    int iResult;
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

// ======================================================================================================
// Création du Socket : 
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                *ptr = NULL,
                hints;

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET ;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    #define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo("10.10.100.254","8899" , &hints, &result); //"10.10.100.254" DEFAULT_PORT  "8899"
    if (iResult == 0) {
        printf("\n\t\tgetaddrinfo, adresse trouvee\n");

        struct addrinfo *res = NULL;
        int error;
        for (res = result; res != NULL; res = res->ai_next)
        {
            char hostname[NI_MAXHOST] = "";

            error = getnameinfo(res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen, hostname, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, 0);
            if (error != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "error in getnameinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(error));
                continue;
            }
            if (*hostname != '\0')
            {
                printf("hostname: %s\n", hostname);
                ptr=res;
            }
        }
    }else
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // Attempt to connect to the first address returned by
    // the call to getaddrinfo


    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

// ======================================================================================================
// Connect to a socket :
    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        switch(WSAGetLastError())
        {
        case WSAEHOSTUNREACH:
            wprintf(L"\n\t\tNo route to host. A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host. See WSAENETUNREACH.\n");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    }

    // Should really try the next address returned by getaddrinfo
    // if the connect call failed
    // But for this simple example we just free the resources
    // returned by getaddrinfo and print an error message

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

// ======================================================================================================
// Send and recive data : 
    #define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    //char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

    // Send an initial buffer

    for(int i = 0; i<100;i++)
    {
        if(sendCommand(ConnectSocket,i, i, 0, i)==-1) break;
        Sleep(10);
    }

// Disconnecting the Client : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530743(v=vs.85).aspx
// shutdown the send half of the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
```

this worked fin for me

Answer (score 0):

Your switch to Windows sockets looks good. The only suggestions I'd have is, if you need cross-version compatibility, adding some fallback logic incase WSAStartup fails finding 2.2 that you're requesting.

Other suggestions would be stylistic, mainly to clean up your usage of WSACleanup by consolidating cleanup code for all the cases - such as using an SEH/leave or a goto fail case.

Comment: Well thank you for the advise, I didn't though about cross version but it could be usefull in other projects.

For the stylistic suggestion, you are right, this was more a proof of concept comming directly from microsoft'web site, now it's all in a class with comments and protected values. I also add a bigger error managment using RPCSTATUS.